# Guardar a informação de um contacto em android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a new intent for choosing a contact
        var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick,
            Android.Provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri);
        //Start the contact picker expecting a result
        // with the resultCode '101'
        StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent,101);   // mostra a lista dos contactos do telefone, so com as pessoas com email.
    }
```

o meu código é este, quando clico no botão aparecem me todos os contactos do utilizador com email.
E o que eu queria era saber como guardo essa informação, por exemplo o utilizador selecciona uma pessoa dos seus contactos e eu quero mandar um email a essa pessoa, mas para isso preciso de guardar as informações do contacto e é isso que eu não sei fazer.

Obrigado a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobrescreva o método `OnActivityResult`, onde no data ele te retornará as informações do contato selecionado conforme no exemplo a seguir:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(data.Data, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.MoveToFirst();

    var columnNumber = cursor.GetColumnIndex(Phone.Number);
    var phoneNumber = cursor.GetString(columnNumber);

    var columnName = cur.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.ContactNameColumns.DisplayNamePrimary);
    var name = cursor.GetString(columnName);
}
```

Comment: Resultou, muito obrigado.

Comment: Nesse caso está apenas pegando o nome e o número do contato, mas você tem outras colunas, sendo possível você pegar o retorno de todas elas no método `GetColumnNames()` que te retornará um array de strings com todos os nomes de colunas possíveis

Comment: mas também vai depender do que eu puser no meu `contactPickerIntent` , no meu exemplo so retorna o email e o nome, o numero está a 0.

Comment: Exato, caso deseja pegar o número, a chamada deve ser feita da seguinte forma:

`var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick,
            Android.Provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri);
            //Start the contact picker expecting a result
            // with the resultCode '101'
            StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 101);`

Comment: mas se eu desejar pegar o email e o numero como faço?